# How can the User ID in Firebase Authentication be the same across all Authentication Providers (Google, Facebook, Github)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

Google says in this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sGY55yxicA&t=1m3s

> The user information contains a unique id which is guaranteed to be
>   distinct across all providers.

How can that be possible if the users have different emails and passwords on each provider? How does Google know which Facebook, Google and Github Account belongs to the same user?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Firebase to link auth providers together.

The workflow is fairly simple, you could have a user authenticated by Google, when logged in they can link their account to Facebook, or the a username / password combination.

This way whenever they login they come in with the same User ID. 
The Auth object will come back with the different providers linked to the Auth user.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking for more information.